# Наложение слоев

Tags: изображения

Даны два растровых изображения одинакового размера, цвета пикселей которых заданы в цветовом 
пространстве RGB с глубиной цвета 8 бит на каждую цветовую координату:
[image]
Исходное изображение 2 было вставлено слоем поверх исходного изображения 1 в графическом редакторе, 
который поддерживает различные режимы наложения слоев. После этого для слоя с исходным 
изображением 2 были выставлены четыре разных режима наложения слоев. В результате были получены 
следующие четыре изображения:
[image]

Известно, что применялись режимы наложения слоев, перечисленные ниже. В случае применения каждого 
из этих режимов значения цветовых координат R, G и B в результирующем изображении рассчитываются 
независимо для каждой координаты по одинаковым формулам. В формулах C1 означает значение 
соответствующей цветовой координаты в исходном изображении 1, С2 – значение этой цветовой 
координаты в исходном изображении 2, а Cr – значение этой цветовой координаты в результирующем 
изображении.

[image]

Определите, какой из режимов наложения слоев применялся для получения каждого из приведенных выше 
результирующих изображений. В ответе укажите подряд без пробелов четыре числа. Сначала номер в 
списке режима наложения слоев, который применен для получения первого результирующего изображения, 
затем номер режима, примененного для получения второго изображения, затем для третьего и 
соответственно для четвертого.
Примечание: значения некоторых цветов на приведенных изображениях могут отличаться от получаемых 
по приведенным формулам на несколько единиц.

Вопросы:

1. Как рассчитывается значение
   цветовой координаты в изображении?
   (в задании это C1, C2)
2. Как вообще рассуждать в таких заданиях? (а то постоянно вызывают затруднение, не
   могу ориентироваться вообще в этих пикселях, RGB...)

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Хочу отметить, что вопрос не предполагает решение задачи за автора.  Помощь автору по этим двум вопросам не есть решение задачи за ТС.  
Тревога- излишне.

Comment: Очевидно самый простой метод проверки этих уравнений блендинга просмотр тех мест на картинках где смешиваются простые цвета. Например если перемножить Red(255,0,0) с Cyan(0,255,255) получится ноль то есть черный из этого делаем вывод что Multiply - Var2_CR1.bmp. Не очень сложная задача

Comment: помойму, 0 - это черный

Comment: Да перепутал черный с белым исправил. 10-ая задача в этом списке классная. Так и представляю пачку несчастных школьников незнакомых с регулярными выражениями и нещадно пытающихся решить ее очередным костылем.

Comment: ахаха, дааа, сложно тем кто на паскале и т.д. у них нет рег. выражений

Comment: @igumnov Подскажите, пожалуйста, как 10-ую задачу решить регулярными выражениями. Хоть я сторонник парсинга текста регулярными выражениями, но в варианте 1 мне приходит в голову только побайтовый просмотр адресов со счетчиком ошибок.  
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @ReinRaus ввод строки - преобразование её в регулярное выражение прямо в коде - сопоставление паттерна со строками входного файлла в цикле - вывод - PROFIT!!! 9 баллов, пятерка по информатике, недоумевающие лица преподавателей, зависть одноклассников, вздохи одноклассниц, жаль я уже давно не школьник :( Осталось придумать подходящий паттерн, поскольку поиск нечеткий нужно воспользоваться чем-то вроде TRE http://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regex-syntax/

Comment: @igumnov и все бы было и девушки жаждущие супер-программиста и море халявного пива от хозяина бара восторгающегося чОткими регулярками, но вот только я для решения этой задачи регулярными выражениями вижу только один выход:  
на основе входной строки **s** делать около **len(s)*(len(s)-1)** регулярных выражений в цикле, что является большим костылем, чем вариант мой в первом комментарии. То есть в цикле генерировать выражения на входную строку **абв**:  

    .бв
    а.в
    аб.
    ..в
    .б.
    а..

Comment: P.S. Если есть другой вариант- буду благодарен, если его покажете, было бы здорово еще прокачать свое владение регулярными выражениями :)  
На текущем уровне я хороших путей решения не вижу :(

Comment: @ReinRaus Да тут похоже квадратичная сложность, я почему-то подумал что можно придумать одно выражение на проход. Тогда здесь нужны алгоритмы нечеткого поиска вроде расстояний Левенштейна, алгоритма расширения выборки, вероятностные алгоритмы вроде поиска подстроки из входной строки в словаре и.т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цветовая координата в данном случае - это цвет пикселя (точки на изображении), представленный в формате RGB. Этот формат представляет все цвета как смесь красного (R), зелёного (G) и синего (B) цветов в разных пропорциях. Доля каждого цвета задаётся числом от 0 до 255. Пример: RGB(255, 0, 0) - красный, RGB(255, 255, 0) - жёлтый, RGB(0, 255, 255) - салатовый, RGB(255, 255, 255) - белый, RGB(0, 0, 0) - чёрный. Попробуй в Paint в расширенной палитре повыбирать цвета и посмотри, какие значения RGB какому цвету соответствуют. Остальное - дело техники. Во 2 картинке явно пределяются цвета: (0, 255, 255) и (255, 0, 255). В первой картинке берёшь точку, в которой цвет определяется достаточно точно (например, точку чистого красного цвета), а потом подставляешь в формулы каждую составляющую по отдельности и получаешь цвет результирующего пикселя. Ищешь соответствие на результирующих картинках. Возможно, придётся взять на первой картинке несколько точек, чтобы однозначно определить соответствие.

Comment: Ну вот смотрите, я лично не понял как будет работать вот эта вещь(255 - C1), т.е. возьмем RGB(0, 255, 255) - салатовый, со второй картинки, и возьмем RGB(255, 0, 0) - красный, с первой картинки , подставим их в формулу 4 и получим цвет RGB(255,255,255) - белый, т.е. 4 - Var2_cr4, но в ответе указан другое соответсвие

Comment: Пересчитай внимательнее. Для каждой составляющей условие вычисляется заново. Красная: C1 = 255, C2 = 0. C1 > 128 => Cr = 255 - (255 - 255) * (255 - 0) / 127 = 255. Зелёная: C1 = 0, C2 = 255. C1 < 128 => Cr = 0 * 255 / 128 = 0. Синяя: C1 = 0, C2 = 255. C1 < 128 => Cr = 0 * 255 / 128 = 0. Получается (255, 0, 0), это вторая или третья картинка.

Comment: первая картинка multiply, вторая color dodge, третья overlay, четвертая screen.  
прикольная задачка.

Comment: а все понял! спасибо

Comment: Смотрите, а вот берем мы 2 и 3 результирующее изображение и 3 и 4 формулу. подставляем в формулы цвет красный(самый правый на 1 изобр), возьмем салатовый(верхний цвет со 2 изобр), подставляем в формулы и получаем в обоих случаях красный цвет (255, 0, 0), перепроверил уже не раз, но на 2 результирующем изображении, получается желтый! помогите как так то? в чем может быть ошибка?